# ViewPager does not show correct page

Tags: android, android-fragments, caching, android-viewpager, adapter

I have a viewPager and I add fragments inside it.
At first I have 4 fragments, showing the last one. 5, 6, 7 ,8
When I reach the first fragment. I make a Api Call, get the data for another 4 earlier fragments: 1,2, 3, 4. And I set the last one as vizible.
My issue is that going through them. I get this: 8, 7 ,6 ,5, 8, 7, 6, 5.
If I exit and reenter the fragment, it works fine. but always the first time, it seems to have the other fragments cached somehow?

This is how I create the fragments:

```
 private List<PSActivityFragment> getFragments(){
    UserRecord profile = UserRecord.getMyUser(PSProfileActivity.this);
    CrudStateCallback crudStateCallback = new CrudStateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String string) {
        }
    };
    List<PSActivityFragment> fList = new ArrayList<PSActivityFragment>();
    if(profile != null) {
        loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(profile.getMonths().size() > 0) {
            for (PSUserActivityMonth month : profile.getMonths()){
                Log.i("","month is fragments created are:" + month);
                PSActivityFragment psaf1 = new PSActivityFragment();
                psaf1.init(month, crudStateCallback);
                fList.add(psaf1);
            }
        }
    }else{
        loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return fList;

}
```

Each time I get new data. I recreate the adapter:

```
  pager.removeAllViews();
    pager = null;
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    final List<PSActivityFragment> fragments = getFragments();
    myPagerAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    pager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
```

I tried instead of recreating and setting the adapter again to just set the fragments to the adapter again, and call notifyDataSetChanged. But still, I get the same issue. Are the fragments cached somewhere? why does this happen?
I checked the log and the fragments are created in the normal order:

```
 06-02 14:16:21.514: I/(14192): month is fragments created are:PSUserActivityMonth{category='u/23', month=11, year=2015, weeks=1}
 06-02 14:16:21.515: I/(14192): month is fragments created are:PSUserActivityMonth{category='u/23', month=12, year=2015, weeks=5}
 06-02 14:16:21.515: I/(14192): month is fragments created are:PSUserActivityMonth{category='u/23', month=1, year=2016, weeks=5}
 06-02 14:16:21.515: I/(14192): month is fragments created are:PSUserActivityMonth{category='u/23', month=2, year=2016, weeks=5}
 06-02 14:16:21.515: I/(14192): month is fragments created are:PSUserActivityMonth{category='u/23', month=3, year=2016, weeks=5}
 06-02 14:16:21.516: I/(14192): month is fragments created are:PSUserActivityMonth{category='u/23', month=4, year=2016, weeks=5}
 06-02 14:16:21.516: I/(14192): month is fragments created are:PSUserActivityMonth{category='u/23', month=5, year=2016, weeks=6}
 06-02 14:16:21.516: I/(14192): month is fragments created are:PSUserActivityMonth{category='u/23', month=6, year=2016, weeks=1}
```

These are months: I should see after cycling through the pager this:
june 16, may 16 , april 16 , march 16 (first for) and then feb 16, jan 16, dec 15, nov15.
Instead I see: june 16, may 16 , april 16 , march 16 (first for) and then june 16, may 16 , april 16 , march 16 again

Adapter code:

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private List<PSActivityFragment> fragments;


public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<PSActivityFragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override

public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}


@Override

public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}

}
```

PS: My activity extends fragmentActivity, and I ma using a getSupportFragmentManager as you can see when I create the adapter. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Can you post adapter code?

Comment: I have posted it, should I also post how the fragment is done? Don't see how it could be revelant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a Activity with FragmentActivity and getSupportFragmentManager. I thought that that might be the issue so I  did this:

```
 if(getSupportFragmentManager() != null && getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() != null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().clear();
    }
```

And now it works!!!